# calling a jQuery event multiple times with different code block for execution

Tags: jquery

This is a peculiar situation. I have an anchor tag and on click of the anchor tag, a function from a jquery plugin executes. But on certain pages, I would like to execute another javascript function on click of the anchor tag. That would mean, my jQuery plugin has a default click event defined for the anchor tag and I will implement another click event on my page for the same anchor tag which calls a different function. As of now only one click event is firing replacing the other. I came up with a solution by using click() for plugin and mouseUp() for calling a function on certain pages.

But basically i want to understand is there a way to combine logic to a jquery even in different places and expect it to execute all of them?

Comment: You have the control on the page and you may have the script in a separate file, but when page is loaded is loaded along the calling page, the click event will fire the same event defined in your script file. What you can do is check the page from where script is calling and place your logic under if..else, otherwise i think it is not possible to override the functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery [Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but in general I'd suggest you wrap your anchor in a parent element with some kind of id or class.  Then use that to determine what to call.  For instance:

JS:

```
function doThis(event) {

}

function doThat(event) {
  doThis(event);
  // more code for doThat...
}

$('.home #nav a').click(doThis);

$('.content #nav a').click(doThat);
```

HTML for home page:

```
<body class="home"><div id="nav"><a href="#">nav 1</a><a href="#">nav 2</a></div></body>
```

HTML for other page:

```
<body class="content"><div id="nav"><a href="#">nav 1</a><a href="#">nav 2</a></div></body>
```

Comment: what i meant is, in one place only doThis should fire and in other place both doThis and doThat should fire.

Comment: Updated answer works when we have control over both functions.. :) in my case one function is part of a jQuery plugin which i can't modify. However your solution is a valid one.. :)